# error MIDL2003: Redefinition : 'x'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, idl, midl

I'm migrating an old C++ project to Visual Studio 2013. The project contains an `.odl` file. When I try to build the project I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error   3   error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting ; near "{" C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  888 1   
Error   2   error MIDL2003: redefinition : Int64ShllMod32   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  888 1   
Error   1   error MIDL2003: redefinition : INT  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h  387 1
```

In the `.odl` file are imported the following `idls`:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "mshtml.idl";
```

I've tried the workaround from the following link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/06/12/com-interface-redefinition-error.aspx  but it didn't solved my problem.

I don't have any redefinition of `Int64ShllMod32` or `INT` in my project files. Any idea what can cause these errors ? 
Thank you !

Comment: The MIDL_PASS macro is not defined for some mysterious reason.  [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried that workaround and I still have the same issues. Also, I've tried with and "empty" `.idl` ( ony the import statements ) and I have the same errors. I've found out that if I change the project settings `Platform Toolset from Visual Studio 2013 (v120) to Visual Studio 2013 Windows Xp (v120_xp )`  the empty project builds succesfully.

Comment: I've tried to use Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio 2013 ( on Windows 8.1 )  and my empty idl and odl files ( they contain only the import statements ) are building succesfully. What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a pretty similar problem and what fixed it was changing the version of Windows SDK to a more recent one ! Hope this helps ! :)